# Incorporate a concatenation and count in a SQL update command?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, concatenation

I am looking for a way to update records so each entry adds 1 to the end of the string. In my case, I'm trying to update a field named FiberID. Each Record should have JCK0.R000.Ax, where x is equal to 1,2,3...,24.

Ideal result:

```
FiberID
JCK0.R000.A1
JCK0.R000.A2
JCK0.R000.A3
```

... and so on until it reaches A24.

Here is an example of the data.

[image]

This seems so useful that I'm sure it has been discussed here before, but for what ever reason I'm not seeing anything.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, will do, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use an row_number and an updatable CTE:

```
with cte as (
    select 
        fiber_id,
        concat(
            fiber_id,
            '.A',
            cast(row_number() over (partition by fiber_id order by id) as varchar(2))
        ) new_fiber_id
    from mytable
)
update cte set fiber_id = new_fiber_id
```

This assumes that you have a column called `id` that can be used to *order* records having the same `fiber_id`.

Side note: it is unclear why you should have exactly 24 numbers per `fiber_id`, and you sample data does not describes that. This will assign increasing numbers to duplicate `fiber_id`s, regardless of how many there are.